# Is there a block limit in paws for amazon textract?

Tags: r, amazon-textract

I am using the following code to analyze and get all the tables of a pdf document I have in an S3 bucket (based in [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/using-r-with-amazon-web-services-for-document-analysis/)):

```
textract <- paws::textract()

analyze_document <- function(bucket, file) {
  
  # Start analyzing the PDF.
  resp <- textract$start_document_analysis(
    DocumentLocation = list(
      S3Object = list(Bucket = bucket, Name = file)
    ),
    FeatureTypes = "TABLES"
  )
  
  # Check that the analysis is done and get the result.
  count <- 0
  while (count < 90 && (!exists("result") || result$JobStatus == "IN_PROGRESS")) {
    Sys.sleep(1)
    result <- textract$get_document_analysis(
      JobId = resp$JobId
    ) 
    count <- count + 1
  }
  return(result)
}

analysis <- analyze_document("bucket", "document.pdf")
```

However, when I try to extract the tables, I only get 2 of the 5 that do exist in the document. When I do `length(analysis$Blocks)` I get exactly 1000 elements, therefore I think I might be getting to an imposed limit.

The thing is that my pdf document only has 7 pages, so it does not make any sense I cannot get the entire content of the PDF

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.185/reference/services/textract.html
Especially:
If there are more results than specified in MaxResults , the value of NextToken in the operation response contains a pagination token for getting the next set of results. To get the next page of results, call GetDocumentAnalysis , and populate the NextToken request parameter with the token value that's returned from the previous call to GetDocumentAnalysis.

Here's a C# code example:
List blocks = new();

```
    do
    {
        GetDocumentAnalysisResponse getDetectionResponse = null;

        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            getDetectionResponse = await textractClient.GetDocumentAnalysisAsync(getDetectionRequest);
        } while (getDetectionResponse.JobStatus == JobStatus.IN_PROGRESS);

        if (getDetectionResponse.JobStatus == JobStatus.SUCCEEDED)
        {
            getDetectionRequest.NextToken = getDetectionResponse.NextToken;
            blocks.AddRange(getDetectionResponse.Blocks);
        }
    }
    while (getDetectionRequest.NextToken != null);
```